# My VideoJS player messed up

Tags: css, wordpress, html, video.js

I'm newbie learning CSS and HTML through the internet and i'm going to host a cartoon website but the fact that haven't know anything about wordpress just a little.

This is my problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVaYv.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vouqa.png

You can see that my player messed up when i start and idk why here the code

```
<video id="video" class="video-js" width="1000" height="500" controls preload="auto" poster="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MmeAPpEoGAI/maxresdefault.jpg" controls data-setup='{}'>
   <source src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/vvT0ZbARuW8E17sX9MbpbFJ81fe_p_TlzSPSWwn3bVVXzPeN6bMsW3h0YsUaAsoxyw5dGkKAHBw=m18" type='video/mp4' label='360p' />
   <source src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/vvT0ZbARuW8E17sX9MbpbFJ81fe_p_TlzSPSWwn3bVVXzPeN6bMsW3h0YsUaAsoxyw5dGkKAHBw=m22" type='video/mp4' label='720p'/>
   <source src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/vvT0ZbARuW8E17sX9MbpbFJ81fe_p_TlzSPSWwn3bVVXzPeN6bMsW3h0YsUaAsoxyw5dGkKAHBw=m37" type='video/mp4' label='1080p'/>
</video>
<script>
  videojs('video').videoJsResolutionSwitcher()
</script>
```

BTW am i adding videoJS in right way ? [I add this in header.php of the theme]

```
<head>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.10.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.10.4/video.js"></script>
<link href="http://127.0.0.1/videojs-resolution-switcher.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/videojs-resolution-switcher.js"></script>
```

The player showing fine with the expamle from videojs.com

Comment: Please can someone help me ....

Answer (score 0):

Try to change stylesheet order

Put videojs style `<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.10.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">` file at the end of the stylesheets queue (the last in the `<head>` section)

It seems that your template styles overwrite videojs styles